# jQuery UI DatePicker to show date range in drop down

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using DataPicker to grab a specific date range to query the database.

However, rather than using the calendar, I want to implement a simple dropdown menu where user only aloow to select a fixed range(e.g., **Today, This Week, This Month, This Year**)

Something like this:

[image: dropdown sample]

Is it possible to change the DatePicker so that it shows this drop down menu instead of a calendar?

Comment: I think for your solution your best bet is to just create the select with those fixed options and handle them server side, no need to use a datepicker if you're not planning on using the date picking functionality of it.

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092288/date-range-picker-on-jquery-ui-datepicker