# how to set the range to enter date of birth in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc, daterangepicker, datapicker

I want to restrict the user to enter date of birth as today's date. Currently i am using the range from 1900 until current year.
How to make the range from 1900 to a day before today e.g Today the date is 20/03/2014. The user should be able to enter date of birth from *1900 to 19/03/2014*.

This is the script i am currently using

```
setDatePicker($("#date_of_birth_str"),"dd/mm/yy");
var currYear = '<fmt:formatDate  value="${now}" pattern="yyyy"/>';
$("#date_of_birth_str").datepicker("option","yearRange", "1900:"+currYear);`
```

Comment: This question has already been answered here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092288/date-range-picker-on-jquery-ui-datepicker>

Comment: Doesn't help i checked already.    if instead of currYear i have currDate will that help. how do we get the current date here

Comment: I'm sorry, what about here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8574442/how-to-add-validation-restrictions-for-html5-date-field-without-jquery-javascrip>?

Comment: setting yearrange will not stop it on particular date -- u have to set min/max date ..u have to try something like this  - http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2013/04/restrict-start-date-range-in-jquery-datepicker.html

Comment: i tried using this but it doesn't work  `$("#date_of_birth_str").datepicker({
   minDate: "01/01/01",
          maxDate: new Date()
          });`

Comment: not works means u can select dates more than today date ?

Comment: yes.. exactly. i can choose dates more than today and the date range is coming from 2004 until 2024.. i want it to be from 01/01/1901 to one day before todays date

Comment: Well i tried in this demo its works .. http://jsfiddle.net/dxbtp/97/