# Materialize Datepicker - picking a range

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I would like to use the materializecss Datepicker in order to pick 2 dates in one Picker. Basically i want to have a start and an end date in one picker. Is this achievable with the component itself or can i modify it somehow to make it work ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092288/date-range-picker-on-jquery-ui-datepicker

Comment: unfortunately this is jqueryui, we would like to use the materialize one. Thanks tho !

Comment: Materializecss does not have a build in function to do this. You will have to do it yourself. That code has a working example of what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe im being dumb here but from my understanding the materializecss picker is based on pickadate.js and the jqueryui datepicker is not. Also - i cant find the onselect event in the pickadate.js documentation at all...

Comment: I had a look around on pickadate github. But it seems this does not have a build in feature either. They are planning on adding it but that had been said in 2013 and it seems it still has not been added. [PickADate.js](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/issues/83)

Answer (score 0):

In javascript use:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
```